# SQL Server connection string to a remote server

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a remote SQL Server Express (2008 R2) with an IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xx and an instance name: myInstance.

I have been trying to connect to a DB (myDB) as user (dbUser) and with password (myPass).

I have tried various string combinations but none works. I am sure I got it wrong because the server is ok, I can ping the IP Address, SQL Server runs on port 1433, which is open. I have also enabled browser service and remote connection on the server.

Please someone give me the correct string...

Comment: What is not working? What _is_ happening? Any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: Usually default instances bind to default 1433 port. Leave `Network Address` or any port configuration out of the connect string. Just use `Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE` and let the provider figure out the port.

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Configure Express to accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this, however, you didn't post any useful details such as error messages or what exception was thrown (if any).

Check that Windows Firewall allows access on port 1433 - this is the most likely reason for the failure, since you are using an IP address and not the name of the instance.

I suggest looking at http://connectionstrings.com to check your connection string.

Comment: sorry for the omission. This is the connection string I'm using: _Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=XX.XX.XXX.XX\AXLECONTROL;User ID=dbUser;Password=myPass;Initial Catalog=myDB;Network Address=XX.XX.XXX.XX,1433_ and the error is: _[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security Error_